# RelayCommand property in a control (SL, MVVM)

Tags: silverlight, mvvm-light, relaycommand

is it possible to create a Silverlight control, which one has a bindable RelayCommand<MyType> property?

If yes, please show me an example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, use a `DependencyProperty` of type `RelayCommand`.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx fore more info on dependency properties.